# Is there some replacement for Quicken Home Inventory on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, quicken

I have Quicken Home Inventory from Intuit and now I got a new computer with Windows 7 and it won't run. I'm looking for some other inventory program, that can load all the data I have.

I looks like QHI does not have export option, and it would be too much to type it all in again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Attic Manager](http://www.guacosoft.com/attic), it has an option to [load Quicken database](http://www.guacosoft.com/qhi) directly.

It works on all Windows versions, and it's even cheaper than QHI.

Comment: Looks good. It seems that it can load the database even if I don't have QHI installed?

Comment: Loading works on Windows XP and Windows 7, you just need to install some software. Take a look at the second link I gave in my post.

Comment: Seems to do the job well. It imported all my data and now I can finally switch off my old Windows XP and switch to seven completely. Thanx.